# Large object heap waste

Tags: c#, .net

I noticed that my application runs out of memory quicker than it should. It creates many byte arrays of several megabytes each. However when I looked at memory usage with vmmap, it appears .NET allocates much more than needed for each buffer. To be precise, when allocating a buffer of 9 megabytes, .NET creates a heap of 16 megabytes. The remaining 7 megabytes cannot be used to create another buffer of 9 megabytes, so .NET creates another 16 megabytes. So each 9MB buffer wastes 7MB of address space!

Here's a sample program that throws an OutOfMemoryException after allocating 106 buffers in 32-bit .NET 4:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharpMemoryAllocationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffers = new List<byte[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 130; ++i)
            {
                buffers.Add(new byte[9 * 1000 * 1024]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can increase the size of the array to 16 * 1000 * 1024 and still allocate the same amount of buffers before running out of memory.

VMMap shows this:

[image]

Also note how there's an almost 100% difference between the total Size of the Managed Heap and the total Commited size. (1737MB vs 946MB).

Is there a reliable way around this problem on .NET, i.e. can I coerce the runtime into allocating no more than what I actually need, or maybe much larger Managed Heaps that can be used for several contiguous buffers?

Comment: Your desire for memory allocations that exactly fit what you need is trumped by a much greater concern, the need to avoid address space fragmentation.  This behavior is entirely by design, there are no knobs to tweak it.  Old fashioned problem anyway, it is a non-issue on 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately this process has to be 32-bit. So you're basically saying I need to code my own allocator?

Comment: Well, why not.  Or you could just write smarter code that needs less memory.  Reuse those arrays.

Comment: @HansPassant. They all contain data that's actually needed so short of dumping them to disk there's not much else to do.

Comment: Can you show the types that are stored in that array? And how many elements are in each array? Or is it 9-10MB of bytes?

Comment: "Reuse those arrays" -- or segment them. Should be straightforward to write a wrapper class with an indexer property to manage an array made up of 2MB segments. But, this is just an optimization with logarithmic ROI. If outgrowing the 32-bit VM due to fragmentation, its a matter of time when you'll outgrow without fragmentation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen They're really just byte arrays. It's high-resolution image data - one buffer is one image.

Comment: How much slower would your code run if you split each array in 4 and rewrote all the code that accessed them? Do you have to compute the array number to index into on each access, or could you process each of the 4 sub-arrays pretty much the same way as before, you just have to switch to a different array at various index points? (or 8, etc.)

Comment: These buffers are sometimes pinned and used by highly optimized unmanaged code that assumes contiguous memory. But, it might be possible to store them splitted and copy them to a contiguous buffer at the point of use - that's a potential solution although not a pleasant one.

Comment: You could allocate your buffers in blocks of 7 (i.e. `new byte[7 * 9 * 1000 * 1024]`), which is pretty close to 64M.

Comment: Can you create a larger buffer with sub 128MB size, that contains several of your smaller objects with 9MB each (12 or 13 objects), in a way that those 128MB will be allocated in a block?

Answer (score 6):

Internally the CLR allocates memory in segments. From your description it sounds like the 16 MB allocations are segments and your arrays are allocated within these. The remaining space is reserved and not really wasted under normal circumstances, as it will be used for other allocations. If you don't have any allocation that will fit within the remaining chunks these are essentially overhead.

As your arrays are allocated using contiguous memory you can only fit a single of those within a segment and hence the overhead in this case.

The default segment size is 16 MB, but if you allocation is larger than that the CLR will allocate segments that are larger. I'm not aware of the details, but e.g. if I allocate 20 MB Wmmap shows me 24 MB segments.

One way to reduce the overhead is to make allocations that fit with the segment sizes if possible. But keep in mind that these are **implementation details** and could change with any update of the CLR.

Answer (score 3):

The CLR reserving a 16MB chunk in one go from the OS, but only actively occupying 9MB.

I believe you are expecting the 9MB and 9MB to be in one heap. The difficulty is that the variable is now split over 2 heaps.

```
 Heap 1 = 9MB + 7MB
 Heap 2 = 2MB
```

The problem we have now, is if the original `9MB` is deleted, we now have 2 heaps we can't tidy up, as the contents are shared across heaps.

To improve performance, the approach is to put them in single heaps.

If you are worried about memory usage, don't be. Memory usage is not a bad thing with .NET, as it if no-one is using it, what's the problem? The GC will at some point kick in, and memory will be tidied up. GC will only kick in either

1. When the CLR deems it necessary
2. When the OS tells the CLR to give back memory
3. When forced to by the code

But memory usage, especially in this example shouldn't be a concern. The memory usage stops CPU cycles occurring. Otherwise if it tidied up memory constantly, your CPU would be high, and your process (and all others on your machine) would run much slower.

Comment: It is worth noting that these allocation all go to the large object heap which means that the GC won't do much to tidy this heap up. LOH fragmentation is not uncommon in .NET applications.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Absolutely! Anything greater than 85'000 bytes goes to the back of the queue for GC.

Comment: Memory usage is bad when I get OutOfMemoryException. GC doesn't matter because I actually am using these buffers. I'm looking for ways to not waste 40% of my address space while allocating several ~9MB buffers - that's my question.

Comment: @Asik: You're filling memory and keeping all of the variables. It can't GC as every variable in that method needs to be retained.

Comment: I know that, that's what I just said.

Comment: @Asik: have you tried allocating 8MB arrays instead, so you get 2 per heap?

Comment: Yes, that works. Unfortunately my application often needs 9 or 10MB arrays.

Comment: I agree with most of the answer, but as far as "dont worry", he is experiencing out of memory conditions (as is documented for large heap), so he pretty much has no other option but to worry.

Comment: What's in those arrays? Have you considered reducing the size of the data in them? Or is it 9-10MB of *bytes*? What I mean is that if you're storing structs, have you looked into reducing the size of each individual struct slightly to get below the 8MB border?

Answer (score 3):

Age old symptom of the buddy system heap management algorithm, where powers of 2 are used to split each block recursively, in a binary tree, so for 9M the next size is 16M. If you dropped your array size down to 8mb, you will see your usage drop by half. Not a new problem, native programmers deal with it too.

The small object pool (less than 85,000 bytes) is managed differently, but at 9MB your arrays are in the large object pool. As of .NET 4.5, the large object heap doesn't participate in compaction, large objects are immediately promoted to generation 2.

You can't coerce the algorithm, but you can certainly coerce your user code by figuring out what sizes to use that will most efficiently fill the binary segments.

If you need to fill your process space with 9 MB arrays, either:

1. Figure out how to save 1MB to reduce the arrays to 8MB segments
2. Write or use a segmented array class that abstracts an array of 1 or 2MB array segments, using an indexer property. Same way you build an unlimited bitfield or a growable ArrayList. Actually, I thought one of the containers already did this.
3. Move to 64-bit

Reclaiming fragmented portion of a buddy system heap is an optimization with logarithmic returns (ie. you are approximately running out of memory anyway). At some point you'll have to move to 64-bit whether its convenient or not, unless your data size is fixed.

Comment: Coercing the runtime has various possible meanings. My suggestion in my answer is to allocate your arrays in powers of 2 in keeping with the buddy algorithm, otherwise you are just fighting against it. You can't replace the heap algorithm / GC, so work with it.

Comment: FWIW, 4.5.1 adds `System.Runtime.GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode` but that's not super-relevant if he's actually using the memory.

Comment: @EricLaw - Oh really? I didn't know about that. That's not even documented in my latest copy of _CLR via C#_. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @EricLaw - For what it's worth, there are GC's in other runtimes that actually do move used memory for compaction. The concept of compaction isn't always dependent on usage. But of course we are talking the CLR.